# How can I use NSVisualEffectView in window's title bar?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, titlebar

In OS X Yosemite, Apple introduced a new class `NSVisualEffectView`. Currently, this class is undocumented, but we can use it in Interface Builder.

How can I use `NSVisualEffectView` in the window's title bar?

Here's example: in Safari, when you scroll, the content appears under the toolbar and titlebar with a vibrance and blur effect.

[image]

Comment: Fortunately, the API documentation for NSVisualEffectView does exist now, for anyone interested:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSVisualEffectView_Class/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@sgonzalez's answer forced me to explore `NSWindow.h` file where i found `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property.

So we get:

```
class BluredWindow: NSWindow {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 180))
    visualEffectView.material = NSVisualEffectView.Material.dark
    visualEffectView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode.behindWindow
    visualEffectView.state = NSVisualEffectView.State.active

    self.styleMask = self.styleMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
    self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    //self.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)



    self.contentView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[visualEffectView]-0-|", 
                                                                   options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.directionLeadingToTrailing,
                                                                   metrics: nil, 
                                                                   views: ["visualEffectView":visualEffectView]))

    self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[visualEffectView]-0-|",
                                                                   options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.directionLeadingToTrailing, 
                                                                   metrics: nil, 
                                                                   views: ["visualEffectView":visualEffectView]))
```

Also you can setup NSVisualEffectView in IB it will be expanded on titlebar.

Comment: Would love to see this in an Objective C version to see if it works with OS 10.8 and up on a Cocoa app.

Comment: @Volomike NSVisualEffectView class was introduced in OS X 10.10.

Comment: Unfortunately, my client requires that my app works on 10.8 and up. So, NSVisualEffectView won't work for me. However, I [did implement it as a test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24025706/105539) and it works, at least on 10.10.

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny : How can I give color with visualeffect ? I done some r&d and found that we need to loop through sublayers of visualEffectView where we have layer name "ClearCopyLayer" and need to give color to this layer. Is there anyother way ?

Comment: @Devang, sorry, but i don't understand you.

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny : Basically i want blurr window with whatever my specific color. Not just Dark and Light but with Specific color

Answer (score 18):

You need to modify your window's stylemask to include `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` so that its content view can "overflow" into it.

You can easily accomplish this by adding this line to your AppDelegate:

```
self.window.styleMask = self.window.styleMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask;
```

If you want it to appear dark, like in FaceTime, you need to also add this line of code:

```
self.window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
```

Comment: There's also a checkbox in IB, just select the Window under the WindowController in the main storyboard, and check "Full Size ContentView" in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Note that you also get this for free if you place a scroll view flush up against the title/toolbar. See also [WWDC 2014 Session 220](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/220/)

Answer (score 9):

#### Step by step Tutorial with examples:

http://eon.codes/blog/2016/01/23/Chromeless-window/

#### Setting up translucency:

1. Set the styleMask of your NSWindow subclass to `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` (so that the translucency will also be visible in the titlebar area, leave this out and the titlebar area will be blank)
2. Set the `self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true` (hides the titlebar default graphics)
3. Add the code bellow to your NSWindow subclass: (you should now have a translucent window)

.

```
let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0))//<---the width and height is set to 0, as this doesn't matter. 
visualEffectView.material = NSVisualEffectMaterial.AppearanceBased//Dark,MediumLight,PopOver,UltraDark,AppearanceBased,Titlebar,Menu
visualEffectView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingMode.BehindWindow//I think if you set this to WithinWindow you get the effect safari has in its TitleBar. It should have an Opaque background behind it or else it will not work well
visualEffectView.state = NSVisualEffectState.Active//FollowsWindowActiveState,Inactive
self.contentView = visualEffectView/*you can also add the visualEffectView to the contentview, just add some width and height to the visualEffectView, you also need to flip the view if you like to work from TopLeft, do this through subclassing*/
```

[image]

#### Also allows you to create chrome-less windows that are translucent:

[image]

Comment: updated. Ill add some more later. Like how you can do it chrom-less.

Comment: This should be the answer. It is the most complete.

Comment: It will get more complete. Putting an end to the confusion about translucency mystiques. Give me 1-2weeks. The thing i want to sort out is how you can combine different translucencies above eachother, there are 2 types you can overlay. Think Safari titlebar and backround of an empty page area. Stay tuned.

Comment: Added a Github gist, drop this code in your AppDelegate class and you have a working translucent window: https://gist.github.com/eonist/0c3cb90b5ad9ebcea83a