# How do you use the dark vibrancy on an NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, appkit, osx-yosemite

What is the correct way to use the Vibrant Dark (`NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark`) or Vibrant Light (`NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight`) modes with an `NSWindow`?

I'm building an application and would like to offer the new Vibrant Dark appearance as an option for the main application's `NSWindow`. The window itself is a pretty straight forward window with an `NSToolbar` across the top and a scroll view as the main content area.

There's plenty of information from Apple on using the new vibrancy appearances in conjunction with an `NSVisualEffectsView`, but I'm looking for clarification on how to use those appearances on an `NSWindow`.

In the `NSAppearance.h` header file, there's a comment that states that the vibrant appearances should only be set on an `NSVisualEffectsView`. There's no mention of it being supported on `NSWindow`.

The WWDC videos talk about making sure that you're using layer-backed views and that you're allowing vibrancy on your subviews when using the new vibrant appearances, but again, no mention of using them on an `NSWindow`.

The VisualEffectsPlayground sample code does have an example of a Facetime-like application that uses the dark vibrancy mode, but it doesn't have a toolbar and it uses the full-content mask.

From that information, I'm doing the following in my `NSWindowController's windowDidLoad` method:

```
[self.window.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
self.window.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
```

And, sure enough, I get a black `NSToolbar` with a black window title bar. So it *looks* like it's working properly, but when my scrollview scrolls its content (thumbnails of images) the standard translucency under the `NSToolbar` and the window's title bar is either not present or is randomly present. There doesn't seem to be any pattern. Sometimes when I scroll the scrollview, the content is shown in the "blurred" state under the toolbar and title bar. Other times when I scroll, the toolbar and titlebar are just an opaque black. (The title bar and toolbar still draw their titles and buttons.)

When I don't request a layer for the window's content view, then I get more a gray titlebar and window title rather than a "pure" black one. (My scrollview's background color can be either white, dark gray or black.)

Any help or clarification on how to properly configure an `NSWindow` (that contains an `NSToolbar` and an `NSScollView`) to use the new vibrancy appearances would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414483/how-can-i-use-nsvisualeffectview-in-windows-title-bar/24439689#24439689

Answer (score 7):

This will make a dark mode window. Subsequently, everything in the window (including titlebar, toolbar and even dialogue sheets) will become dark.

```
    let USE_DARK_MODE = true
    if USE_DARK_MODE {
        window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
        window.invalidateShadow()
    }
```

`invalidateShadow` doesn't seem required, but sometimes shadow does not work properly if lacked. (OS X 10.10)

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to get more of an understanding regarding whether the entire window (`contentView`) needs to be layer backed or not and where, if at all, an NSVisualEffectView needs to be inserted. Just setting the window's `appearance` property is clear to me, what's not entirely clear is how that affects the `effectiveAppearance` of every other control in the window.

Answer (score 3):

I figured that you can subclass `NSWindowController`. Set the class for your Window Controller in IB to your custom `NSWindowController`. After that in the windowDidLoad function

```
self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

Also set "Full Size Content View" in the Attribute inspector for the `NSWindow`.

[image]