# Cocoa - XCode Objective-C make window of app "dark"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have simple question, what I can't find answer on google. How to make window of macOS Cocoa application **dark**? Is it able with XCode without coding or I must write Objective-C to do this. [Image here](https://s23.postimg.org/wo3oowirv/Screen_Shot_2016_12_28_at_4_24_23_AM.png).

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447024/how-do-you-use-the-dark-vibrancy-on-an-nswindow)

First add this code to *viewDidLoad*:

```
self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

And then place **Visual Effect View** on entire window and in window settings check **Full Size Content View**

**TIP:** To hide title of form use this code:

```
self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
```

And Result:
[image]