# Making NSView appearance vibrantDark

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm currently learning Swift, and I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHmAXqpST44) to create an `NSWindow` that inherits the `vibrantDark` property from the AppKit in Swift. The code I added to the WindowController.swift file is as follows:

```
window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
window?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark)
```

What I'd like to do is achieve the same result for an `NSPopover` in my program; however, when I add the following to my LogViewController.swift file, I get an error -- the first of which is "Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'titleVisibility,'" and the second of which is "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'NSView.'"

```
view?.titleVisibility = .hidden
view?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark)
```

Several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447024/how-do-you-use-the-dark-vibrancy-on-an-nswindow) have addressed this issue for `NSWindow`, but I cannot find an answer that addresses `NSPopover`. I currently have the following condition set to open `NSPopover` upon clicking `NSImage` in the status bar:

```
popover.contentViewController = LogViewController.freshController()
```

I'm thinking that having `NSPopover` as `NSView` is what's causing the issue, but -- being as I'm still new to Swift -- I'm not sure how to diagnose this the problem. That said, I would much appreciate it if anyone could point me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an `NSPopover`, not an `NSView`:

```
var myPopover: NSPopover?

myPopover = NSPopover.init()
myPopover?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantDark)
```

If you want to use a `contentViewController`:

```
var popoverViewController: NSViewController?

myPopover?.contentViewController = self.popoverViewController
```

Comment: `NSAppearance.Name` is redundant. `myPopover?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantDark)`. Btw please don't use semicolons in Swift

Comment: @LeoDabus In which file should I be putting this?

Comment: @rrod those are specific NSWindow properties. NSView has no appearance or titleVisibility properties. You can try setting your view window property `view.window?.whatever` as long as the window property it is not nil (try in viewDidAppear method)