# NSScrollView blur in NSPopover

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nsvisualeffectview

I have a couple of `NSScrollView`s inside an NSPopover in my app. I want to create a Safari-like blur with scrolled content on the top. However I can't find any solution, since it is an NSPopover and I cannot set the style mask. I tried adding a blank row with the height of the header and positioning the header (`NSVisualEffectView`) over the `NSScrollView` (table view), and this method works but the scroller goes under the header. So is there a "right way" to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414483/how-can-i-use-nsvisualeffectview-in-windows-title-bar

Comment: I forgot to tell that the whole app is made in NSPopover, because it's a statusbar app. So I can't set window.styleMask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSScrollView provides a nice method called `addFloatingSubview:forAxis:`. It should be possible to add the `NSVisualEffectsView` as a subview of the scroll view then. By using this method, the scroller stays above the header.

To get the scroller stop before the effects view, you can modify the `contentInsets` property of `NSScrollView`.