# Changing colour and opacity of NSWindow

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nswindow, today-extension

I'm working a on a Mac Today Widget and in the companion app that you enter all the information in I want to make the window act/look like the Notification Centre, an example of this is an app called monity. I've looked through documentation and haven't been able to wrap my head around it, this is my first Mac app so any help will be very much appreciated.

Here is an example of what I would like:

- Translucent Window
- Blackish Tint
- MenuBar that fades into window

[image]

Comment: I think it can be accomplished only on 10.10 + SDK
Maybe this will help you to get started
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023183/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-view-with-translucent-blurry-background

Comment: http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame